# How do you bind 2 controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls

In my app, there is a feature to customize it's own Controls (like `Textbox`, `Label`s, `Textblock`s, `Button`s, etc), this feature interface is located inside a `TabItem`. Lets say i want to modify `Button` A, which is located in ANOTHER container. On the feature interface, i set it's `Foreground` property to `White`, at this moment i don't know whether the `Button` looks better or not, so i have to go to the container which contains that `Button`.

What am i trying to do is, i want to create a "preview" `Control` (which is the same type as the actual target) inside the feature interface. I want any changes on this "preview" control are reflected to the actual target `Control`. With this, i won't need to navigate to where the target `Control` located.

When i used the title ("How do you bind 2 controls)" with google, all results actually gives me "how to bind SINGLE `property` of a control to another control's `property`". What i want is how do you bind/link 2 `Control`s literally, i mean, i want to bind ALL properties of `Control` A to ALL properties of `Control` B.

Binding them one by one is one (tiring) way. Is there another way to achieve this?

I would prefer code-behind method.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I did it. Will post the code shortly.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do (and why)? There might be an easier way to do it.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Hi, i've updated my answer, please read it :D

Comment: @Wahyu Oh, that sounds different than what your original question. So you simply want to bind multiple controls to the same data, or create a preview of the settings?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Haha my bad, i myself are confused about how should i ask. Yes, i want to create a preview of settings (of SINGLE control).

Comment: @Wahyu Ok, why don't you just instantiate a new Button/Label/Whatever and apply the settings to that control? To be honest I don't see the problem. Could you add a [mcve] to your question? As it is now I am not certain what's stopping you.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer nvm, i changed my method to do that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "fast" way to do this, you will have to bind one by one according to your buisness logic.
Also a binding is not cheap regarding performance so binding each and every property of a control even those you dont explicitly need, is a warning sign.